# PhpSpreadsheet how to specify date format everywere before toArray

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Is it possible to specify a default date format to be applied everywere before a toArray?

This is my code:

```
$inputFileType = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($myfile);
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($myfile);

$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getSheet(0);
$sheetData = $worksheet->toArray();
```

The $sheetData array is created with date format as specified in the input file, is there an easy way to "force" every date cell to a specified date format?

With this code I can set the specified date format in a specific cell

```
$worksheet->getStyle("E2")->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

but how can I make this a "default" for every date cell?

Comment: `\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Cell::setValueBinder( new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\AdvancedValueBinder() );`. It automatically converts percentages, number in scientific format, and dates entered as strings to the correct format, also setting the cell's style information.

Comment: thanks, but it's not related to my situation, let's assume the input file is correctly formatted with dates in format MM/DD/YYYY, I want to format every date in the loaded file to YYYY-MM-DD or any other format I may be using